# Why are ] and } not considered special characters?

Tags: regular-expressions, syntax

Reading the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) for GNU grep, the special characters (with -E option) are `.?*+{|()[\^$`.

This is a somewhat pedantic question, but why are `]` and `}` omitted? In particular it says in section 3.1 "An unmatched `)` just matches itself", which is true for `]` and `}` as well.

I think it is just a slightly sleeker description of ERE–we can get by without `}` and `]` being special, because their syntactic purpose is served only in a context where specialness fails to be meaningful (that is, after an unmatched `{` or `[` has occurred).

Note that this is not a question about GNU grep per se, but rather about the syntactic rules of ERE.

Comment: My advice is not authoritative, but I would imagine that this spares useless escaping of these right delimiters. The Unix freaks loved compact typing.

Comment: Just a guess: One difference between `()` versus `{}` and `[]` is that `()` can be nested. If you have an unmatched `)` within nested parentheses, you end up with an ambiguous expression.